# dislocated screen

Tags: terminology

From *Situated Software* by Clay Shirky (The author talks about two student projects):

> Both Scout and CoDeck had the classic problem of notification -- getting a user to tune in requires interrupting their current activity, not something users have been known to relish.
>
> Both hit on the same solution: take most of the interface off the PC's **dislocated screen**, and move it into a physical object in the lounge, the meeting place/dining room/foosball emporium in the center of the ITP floor.

What is "dislocated screen"?

Comment: This is a question in English. *Dislocated* generally means *moved from its usual position* (e.g., dislocated shoulder). For the exact meaning here more context is needed.

Comment: This is not a technical term, so I am migrating this question to a site about English.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather odd use of *dislocated*, and it is not surprising you have trouble understanding it.

What Shirky seems to mean is that individual users' PCs are private instruments, separated ('dislocated') from the community which employs and supports these projects. By moving the user interface onto physical devices within the public space where the community gathers, the developers 'relocated' the projects in their proper context.

Answer (score 0):

The screen is dislocated/dislodged from it's chasis.

[image]